# What is the keyword for this effect: an animated person walks out from the bottom right corner of a website?

Tags: website-design, animation, javascript

What is the keyword for this effect: an animated person walks out from the bottom right corner of a website? Better yet, any link to any provider that still exists today?

Anybody know this may feel old :). It was very common in early 2,000s. There was even ready-made javascript I just needed to embed, similar to chatbot nowadays.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"3D Talking Avatar" seems to be the closest phrase that matches what I think you're looking for.

From a UX perspective, they probably went out of style for a reason; avatars give the appearance of being conversational, but they're one-sided. Chat boxes let the user drive the conversation. And it's become a lot easier to incorporate video.

Comment: That and the animated paper paperclip...

Comment: Good old Clippy...